# swift: Items in UIScrollView don't scroll

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I build a view where I display a lot of text and where I need to scroll down, if the texts are to long. When I scroll down, I can see the vertical scrollbar moving, but the view doesn't change. The functions scrollViewWillBeginDragging and scrollViewDidScroll are not used (nothing happens in the console). I also used isScrollEnabled=true but it's not working. Am I missing something?

[image: view]

```
import UIKit
//

class TestView : UIScrollView{

    var testObject: TestObject? {
        didSet {
            //set texts
            ....
            //set height for textViews depending on text
            refreshHeightOfTextViews()
        }
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        isScrollEnabled = true
        contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 2000)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    let dateLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Date:"
        label.font = UIFont(name: (label.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let testALabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "TestA:"
        label.font = UIFont(name: (label.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let testBLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "TestB:"
        label.font = UIFont(name: (label.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let testCLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "TestC:"
        label.font = UIFont(name: (label.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let testDLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "TestD:"
        label.font = UIFont(name: (label.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let contentLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Content:"
        label.font = UIFont(name: (label.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let contentValueTextView : UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "A"
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -4, 0, 0)
        textView.font = UIFont(name: (textView.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isEditable = false
//        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return textView
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        addSubview(dateLabel)
        addSubview(testALabel)
        addSubview(testBLabel)
        addSubview(testCLabel)
        addSubview(testDLabel)
        addSubview(contentLabel)
        addSubview(contentValueTextView)

        setupLabels()
    }

    func refreshHeightOfTextViews() {
        let contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: .infinity)
        let estimatedContentSize = contentValueTextView.sizeThatFits(contentSize)
        contentValueTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: estimatedContentSize.height).isActive = true
    }

    func setupLabels() {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        dateLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        dateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        dateLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        dateLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true

        testALabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        testALabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        testALabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        testALabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLabel.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        testBLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testALabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        testBLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testALabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        testBLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        testBLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLabel.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        testCLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testBLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        testCLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testBLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        testCLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        testCLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLabel.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        testDLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testCLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        testDLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testCLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        testDLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        testDLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLabel.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        contentLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testDLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testDLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        contentValueTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentValueTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentValueTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true            
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("\(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("test")
    }

}


class TestController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var testObject: TestObject? 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let testFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        let testView = TestView(frame: testFrame)
        testView.testObject = testObject
        view.addSubview(testView)

        testView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
        testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for scrollview to scroll properly, you need to to add all your items to a uiView and add that uiView to your scrollView. Your new uiView should have its height set to a larger value than the scrollView. It will also not work unless the heights for both the uiScrollView and uiView are not explicitly set. You basically explicitly tell your application that the containing view inside the scrollView is larger than itself so you should scroll.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViews are not supposed to be used like UIScrollViews by adding subviews.

The collection view content is calculated by the UICollectionViewCells provided by the data source.
You should break the content into Collection View Cells (or put everything into a single one, whatever).

Another options is to create a Supplementary View which should also be provided by the Data Source.

see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource